# SpringBoot RedirectAttributes does not show in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

controller code:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AdminController {
    private AdminUserService adminUserService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam String kaptcha, RedirectAttributes attributes, HttpSession session) {
        String errorMsg;
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(kaptcha)) {
            errorMsg = "kaptcha can't be empty";
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMsg", errorMsg);
            return "redirect:admin/login";
        }
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(username) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            errorMsg = "username or password can't be empty";
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMsg", errorMsg);
            return "redirect:admin/login";
        }
        String code = (String) session.getAttribute(Const.kapchaCode);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(code) || !kaptcha.equals(code)) {
            errorMsg = "invalid kaptcha code";
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMsg", errorMsg);
            return "redirect:admin/login";

        }
        AdminUser login = adminUserService.login(username, password);
        if (login == null) {
            errorMsg = "invalid username password combination";
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMsg", errorMsg);
            return "redirect:admin/login";
        }

        session.setAttribute("loginUser", login.getAlias());
        session.setAttribute("loginUserId", login.getAdminUserId());
        return "redirect:/admin/index";

    }
```

template:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <div th:if="${errorMsg}" class="alert alert-danger" th:text="${errorMsg}"></div>
                </div>
```

errorMsg wouldn't show up when there is an error.
I have checked that errorMsg indeed get into RedirectAttributes, but it wouldn't display on the page;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set the value in redirected controller `admin/login`. Example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String OtherController(@ModelAttribute("errorMsg") String errorMsg, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("errorMsg", errorMsg);
    return "login";//template name
}
```

Comment: still not working.After change to  ```attributes. addAttribute("errorMsg", errorMsg);```

Comment: @Shawn99 thanks for reply, I am learning Spring and misunderstood the problem. Nonetheless I have updated my answer, please check if it works. I assume that you have some-controller for redirect `admin/login`, if you have the controller checkout the updated answer, if not then you need to use `Model#addAttribute` and instead of `return "redirect:admin/login"` simply use `return "login"`